# Refer to an Array Object with the name of a string - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an IOS application that stores a user-select categories in Core Data on the first view and then displays a random item from an array corresponding to the categories selected in the next view.

I have everything working except one part: the categories are saved in Core Data as strings and I need to take the string values and add ARRAY objects with names that correspond to those strings into a larger array.

Start with a For loop that takes the value of the name, then add that object to the array

```
 for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData) {
        name = [obj valueForKey:@"name"];
        [categoryArray addObject:name];
 }
```

I have arrays declared already that correspond to the names that it will retrieve, but I need to add the Object of those ARRAYS not the STRING that is returning from Core Data. I'm new to this sort of problem, as in JS for example this isn't an issue.

Is there an ArrayWithNameLike @"name" function or something?

Comment: Maybe you want to use NSMutableDictionary for this purpose? You can build such Dictionaries composed of name and category and add this objects to your array?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but wouldn't you use `NSDictionary` to retrieve an object with an `NSString` as the key?

Comment: I think that's what we're gonna try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep your arrays of random items in an NSDictionary, keyed off the category NSString. In this example replace  with the array you want associated with that particular category (retrieved through a method, created there, whatever)

```
 self.categoryItemArrays = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[matchingData count]];

 for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData) 
 {
    name = [obj valueForKey:@"name"];
    [self.categoryItemArrays setObject:<Cateogry Array> forKey:name];
 }
```

Then for your datasource you can get the keys and alphabetize them or sort how you want with

```
[self.categoryItemArrays allKeys];
```

and do your thing.

Comment: A good suggestion if you are creating your own model layer.  Not a good idea if using Core Data.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Core Data, you should express the relationships between your objects within your Core Data model.  If you really want to continue down the path of inventing your own relationship management -- nothing wrong with that -- don't use Core Data as you'll just end up fighting it all the time.

---

Sounds like you are trying to re-invent modeled relationships while creating a *Master Detail* interface.

Say you have a managed object called **Book**.  Every **Book** can be in one **Category**.  Every **Category** can have many **Book**s.  *Master detail* refers to if you were building a UI where you select a **Book** (the *master*) and the **Category** is shown in secondary UI.  This can be turned around;  you select a **Category** and the list of **Book**s in that category is shown.

The key is to let Core Data do the work of maintaining the relationships for you.

So, you need a *one-to-many* relationship from **Book** to **Category**.

The [CoreData Books](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) example goes into detail on how to do this.

Comment: You're absolutely right, we're doing this a stupid way. No argument there.

Comment: Been there, done that (an embarrassingly large number of times over the last 20+ years). :)   Sometimes success is built on a crappy foundation.  Acknowledging that is half the battle.